Is 1.5 hours enough for flight transfer in Frankfurt?
I am travelling from India. The first port of entry in Europe is in Frankfurt (terminal 1). The flight out of Frankfurt to Porto (OPO, Portugal) is 1.5 hours later, from the same terminal. Would it be fine? Do I have to clear the immigration as it is the first port of entry? Would appreciate any insights.

Is this a self-transfer? Even if it isn’t, 1.5hours for airside transit seems tight to me, allowing for de-planing and getting to the gate say 20-30 minutes before it closes.

If the flight from India is delayed (which, I suppose, has a non-negligible probability for an intercontinental flight) it may become difficult. How bad it is to miss the connecting flight depends on whether it's a single ticket (in which case the company is responsible and will put you on the next flight) or whether you bought the tickets independently.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica thank you for your insights. In the end, I have decided to take a different flight plan. There are too many variables and 1.5 hours seem too tight to be comfortable. If you should know, the ticket is a single ticket, and all the flights are of a single airline.

Border can easily take 30-45m if you end up on the back of the line in German airports when you're traveling from outside EU (if you don't qualify for the EU line). There's no shame in rushing out of the plane to land on early spot on the line, and there's no shame in asking to move further in the line if you have an urgent matter (like a transfer you're likely to miss otherwise).

@ave If you are on a very short transfer, airline personell will most likely bring you from the arrival gate to the departure gate and make sure, that you get priority at the immigration and security checkpoints. As I already wrote in my answer, the minimum transfer time in Frankfurt is only 45 minutes and Lufthansa would not have sold such connections, if the transfer had not been possible.

You have to clear immigration in Frankfurt, but if this is a through ticket, you will usually have plenty of time with 1.5 hours. The minimum transfer time in Frankfurt is only 45 minutes, even for connections where you must go through immigration and security.
If it is a self-transfer, especially if you have to recheck luggage, you will likely not make it.

Thank you very much! I have not decided to take it though. I am not sure if I have to recheck my luggage though. It is a single ticket and all the flights from India to FRA to OPO are of deutsche Lufthansa.

I did something similar (1.5 hr layover at Frankfurt) about a year ago. Things moved fast enough that I was able to make the transfer. I was travelling to US and didn't had to clear the immigration.

A note to anyone reading this in the future: this is a very different situation, since John was travelling outside of the Schengen area, and therefore there were no immigration formalities in Frankfurt. Since user132001's connection is to a flight within Europe, they would have had to clear immigration in FRA, and if they are Indian they can't take any shortcuts (e-gates, etc).
